# How to create a views page of discounted products list?

Tags: search, commerce, views

I'am using commerce discount module in commerce kickstart 2.11 
And need to create a page with a list of dicounted products using views filter and/or search API.
I've tryed without any success.
Please Anyone, any help to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid there's no working solution right now.

you can see and follow [List all discounted products](https://drupal.org/node/2149777) in commerce discount issue list for further information and workarounds.